# Section, sentence, nos. (German immigration law)

Tags: germany, immigration

Section 18b of the [Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html) contains the next text:

> A foreigner who has successfully completed his studies at a state or state-recognised university or a comparable educational institution in the federal territory shall be granted a permanent settlement permit, if
>   (1..3 omitted) and
>   4.  the requirements of Section 9 (2), sentence 1, nos. 2 and 4 to 9 are met; Section 9 (2), sentences 2 to 6 shall apply accordingly.

Section 9(2) consist of: (it's not necessary to read them all)

> (2) A foreigner shall be granted a permanent settlement permit if
>
> 1. he has held a temporary residence permit for five years,
> 2. his subsistence is secure,
> 3. he has paid compulsory or voluntary contributions into the statutory pension scheme for at least 60 months or furnishes evidence
>      of an entitlement to comparable benefits from an insurance or pension
>      scheme or from an insurance company; time off for the purposes of
>      child care or nursing at home shall be duly taken into account,
> 4. granting such a temporary residence permit is not precluded by reasons of public safety or order, according due consideration to the
>      severity or the nature of the breach of public safety or order or the
>      danger emanating from the foreigner, with due regard to the duration
>      of the foreigner’s stay to date and the existence of ties in the
>      federal territory,
> 5. he is permitted to be in employment, if he is in employment,
> 6. he possesses the other permits required for the purpose of the permanent pursuit of his economic activity,
> 7. he has sufficient command of the German language,
> 8. he possesses a basic knowledge of the legal and social system and the way of life in the federal territory and
> 9. he possesses sufficient living space for himself and the members of his family forming part of his household.

What does 18b #4 mean exactly? Which paragraphs one should satisfy? All from 1 to 9? Why then phrases from 18b are so complicated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a fairly straightforward construction. Section 9(2) and 18b share a number of requirements, so 18b points back instead of repeating them. But not all requirements are shared.

In particular, requirement 3 (covering pensions) does not apply to newly-graduated students. That's not strange since students are not paid wages. Also, they're not subject to the 5 year residence permit requirement.

As for "sentences 2 to 6 shall apply accordingly.", this covers waivers to these requirements.

Comment: So this is like set A  minus set B , where A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and B={?}. From your answer I understand that 3 in set B.Is it true that B={3}? (so A-B = {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9}). Please clarify B = what?

Comment: @ged: I don't know how you define your "set B". Article 18b spells out which requirements do apply: {2,4,5,6,7,8,9}. From that, I deduced that 1 and 3 do not apply. (Namely {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} - {2,4,5,6,7,8,9} = {1,3} )

Comment: @MSalters This is correct. 1=5 years does not apply (overriden by 18b (2) two years) . 3=payment of 5 years into pension fund does not apply (students don't pay into pension funds).

Answer (score 4):

> Section 9 (2), sentence 1, nos. 2 and 4 to 9 are met; Section 9 (2), sentences 2 to 6 shall apply accordingly.

means

Of the first sentence of § 9 (b)

- "A foreigner shall be granted a permanent settlement permit if  ...",

the conditions specified under points 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 must be met.

Additionally, the sentences 2 to 6, i.e.,

- The requirements of sentence 1, nos. 7 and 8 shall be deemed ...
- These requirements shall be waived if the foreigner is ...
- The requirements of sentence 1, nos. 7 and 8 may ...
- The aforesaid requirements shall further be waived if ...
- The requirements of sentence 1, nos. 2 [and 3] shall also be waived if ....

shall apply accordingly. Note that I placed "and 3" in brackets as no. 3 does not need to be met already by the first restriction and so no waiving needs to be discussed.